# KeyError: 'pop from an empty set' python

Tags: python, set

How do you get around this error while using `.pop`? I get that when it tries to return a number but there isn't one an error is raised but how do you get around it so the program keeps running?

```
def remove_element(self,integer):
    self.integer = integer
    self.members.pop()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just check if `self.members` is not empty:

```
if self.members:
    self.members.pop()
```

or, catch `KeyError` via `try/except`:

```
try:
    self.members.pop()
except KeyError:
    # do smth
```

Comment: change that to `KeyError`.  Also better not to use a bare `except` (for example, that would also hide `AttributeError`, etc).

Comment: ... and actually put the `KeyError` in the `except` clause :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `try/except` to catch the `KeyError` raised by `an_empty_set.pop()`, or check the set first to make sure it's not empty:

```
if s:
    value = s.pop()
else:
    # whatever you want to do if the set is empty
```

Answer (score 0):

Single line solution

```
res = self.members.pop() if self.members else None
```